# How to change the default instance of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server, database-administration

we have a dev server. First we had SQL 2000 (default instance), when SQL 2005 came out, we installed it as a named instance. 
Nowadays we barely use the SQL2000 instance, but this is the default. We would like the SQL2005 to be the default instance and make the 2000 a named one. Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You'll need to upgrade the default instance to SQL 2005, remove the 2005 named instance and reinstall SQL 2000 as a named instance.  Or just wipe clean and install SQL 2005 first as the default and SQL 2000 as a named instance.

Any reason you need to keep the SQL 2000 instance around?

Comment: Mmm no... I think we could live without SQL2000, later if we need it, then we can install it as a named instance...
So... I need to uninstall both sql 2000 and 2005 and install 2005 as a default instance. How can I backup the databases, logins, agent schedules etc???

Comment: No need to uninstall.  Although it is a touch cleaner it is a pain.  You can upgrade your SQL 2000 instance to 2005.  Just run the SQL 2005 installer and choose to upgrade the default instance.

Comment: I decided to uninstall the SQL2000. So now I have one named instance of sql2005... if I run the setup I should be able to install a sql2005  as the default instance right? But then I need to move everything from the named instance to the fresh new default instance. Any idea how to do that quick and easy?

Comment: Yes, install 2005 as the default instance.  Note, however, that patching is instance specific so you'll need to bring it up to the same patch level as your named instance.  You can detach/attach databases (or use the copy db wizard which will bring over other objects as well) to move things.

Answer (score 0):

I did step 1 and 2 from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx) and it worked. Didn't have to reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant on this link any more. :(